# How to query Javascript object using SQL when column names contain spaces?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql-server

I want to query a javascript array object using SQL(to perform grouping on data).

```
var data = [{ dep: 'A', qt: 10, price: 5},
 { dep: 'A', qt: 5,  price: 2.30 },
 { dep: 'B', qt: 3,  price: 2.20 },
 { dep: 'C', qt: 1,  price: 4 },
 { dep: 'C', qt: 4,  price: 10 }];

var res = alasql('SELECT dep, SUM(qt) AS qt, SUM(qt*price) AS amt, AGGR(amt/qt) AS price FROM ? GROUP BY dep',[data]);



document.getElementById("res").textContent = JSON.stringify(res);
```

But in my original scenario, I have column names with spaces as:

```
 var data = [{ "dep name": 'A', qt: 10, price: 5},
     { "dep name": 'A', qt: 5,  price: 2.30 },
     { "dep name": 'B', qt: 3,  price: 2.20 },
     { "dep name": 'C', qt: 1,  price: 4 },
     { "dep name": 'C', qt: 4,  price: 10 }];
```

How to modify the above SQL query so that column name with spaces can be used. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use backticks (`) to escape MySQL column names. This allows you to:

```
SELECT A as `dep name` ...
```